# Mathematica + HDF5 basic examples

Tags: export, import, hdf5-format

How to export/import basic Mathematica types using HDF5 file format?

I find that the official [Mathematica doc](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/HDF5.html) is missing some examples.

Comment: CDF means something a bit different in *Mathematica*, so you might wish to clarify somewhere that you're using the "Common Data Format" (cf. [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/154001)).

Comment: @J.M. I just edited my post, thanks

Answer (score 8):

**Exporting data**

To export a *string*, a *scalar* and a *matrix*

```
aString="aString";
aScalar=2017;
aMatrix=Table[Random[],{4},{2}];
```

The syntax is:

```
Export["foo.h5",
       {"Datasets" -> {"aString" -> aString, 
                       "aScalar" -> {aScalar}, 
                       "aMatrix" -> aMatrix},
        "DataFormat" -> {Automatic,Automatic,Automatic}}, "Rules"
]
```

AFAIK you must encapsulate *scalars* in a list (i.d. *{aScalar}*), otherwise you get this

```
Export::errelem: The Export element Datasets contains a malformed data    
structure and could not be exported to HDF5 format.
```

error message.

Also note that we have used **Automatic** for **DataFormat** which is very
convenient especially for **strings**. You can also simply use
**{Automatic}** 
instead of 
**{Automatic,Automatic,Automatic}**.

You can also explicitly define the format types:

```
Export["foo.h5",
       {"Datasets" -> {"aString" -> aString, 
                       "aScalar" -> {aScalar}, 
                       "aMatrix" -> aMatrix},
        "DataFormat" -> {Automatic,"Integer32","Real64"}}, "Rules"
 ]
```

**Importing data**

The command

```
Import["foo.h5"]
```

returns the *datasets* contained in the file

```
 {"/aMatrix", "/aScalar", "/aString"}
```

You can get some extra information, like the data types and their dimensions:

```
 Import["foo.h5", "DataFormat"]
 Import["foo.h5", "Dimensions"]
```

prints

```
 {"Real64", "Integer32", "String"}
 {{4, 2}, {1}, {}}
```

Finally you can import the data set you want:

```
 Import["foo.h5", {"Datasets", "aScalar"}] (* prints {2017} *)
```

or several data sets:

```
 Import["foo.h5", {"Datasets", {"aMatrix", "aString"}}]
```

which prints in my case:

```
 {{{0.840383, 0.0926723}, {0.657987, 0.619812}, {0.975782, 
    0.985007}, {0.604865, 0.515671}}, "aString\.00"}
```

**CAVEAT**: At least under Linux, you must take care that a terminal zero (à la *C*) has been added to the string: *"aString.00"*:

For instance

```
 Import["foo.h5", {"Datasets", "aString"}] == "aString"
```

prints

```
 False
```

AFAIK you have to manually remove this final zero:

```
 StringDrop[
     Import["foo.h5", {"Datasets", {"aString"}}], -1] == "aString"
```

returns

```
 True
```

**Caveat#2:** It seems that this trailing zero is not present under Windows (see comments).

**Note**: this should also work with [NetCDF](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/NetCDF.html) or [NASACDF](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/NASACDF.html) format, just replace the **.h5** file extension by **.nc** or **.cdf**.

Comment: Interesting, which version and OS have you tried that? I have never seen strings with terminating zeros. I just have tried your example and also don't see it there (mma 11.1 on Windows 7). I would consider that a bug...

Comment: I am running under Linux (Debian distro), mma 11. I would not have suspected such difference either. That is an interesting point to clarify, thank you for the comment. Unfortunately, on my side, I have not access to mma under Windows.

Comment: @AlbertRetey I forgot to mention your name in my answer, not sure you read it. Sorry, I just realized that now.

Comment: No problem for not mentioning me, but I think it would make sense to mention that the trailing zero is an OS (and probably version) dependent problem...

Comment: @AlbertRetey you are right, I have edited my post. Thanks.