# Importing data from NASA CDF files using Mathematica

Tags: import, cdf-format

At the outset, I would like to emphasize that I do not have any expertise in loading CDF data files in Mathematica.

Usually, in MATLAB the CDF files can be viewed and loaded with the help of commands such as `cdfinfo`, `cdfread` etc.

```
clear; clc;
CDFDefaultEgInfo=cdfinfo('example.cdf');
CDFDefaultEgRead=cdfread('example.cdf');
```

However, the same command does not work for the CDF files which contains data from satellite missions such as Van Allen Probes, MMS etc:

```
CDFDownloadedWithoutPatchInfo=cdfinfo("rbsp-a_magnetometer_1sec-gsm_emfisis-L3_20140303_v1.3.2.cdf");
```

Here the CDF files are downloaded from this [site](https://emfisis.physics.uiowa.edu/Flight/RBSP-A/L3/2014/03/03/rbsp-a_magnetometer_1sec-gsm_emfisis-L3_20140303_v1.3.2.cdf). You can try the same with another CDF downloaded from [here](https://lasp.colorado.edu/mms/sdc/public/about/browse/mms3/edi/srvy/l2/amb-alt-oc/2016/09/mms3_edi_srvy_l2_amb-alt-oc_20160918_v4.1.0.cdf), but results remain the same: an error

> Error using cdflibmex 33 is not a recognized DATATYPE mode.

In-order circumvent this one, we are supposed to download a [MATLAB patch](https://cdf.gsfc.nasa.gov/html/matlab_cdf_patch.html), extract the files included in the patch to a directory, and then issue the following command at the MATLAB prompt or in pgm. Now instead of cdfinfo we can use spdfcdfinfo, instead of cdfread, we have to use spdfcdfread and then we can do further analysis. The program can now be modified as:

```
clear; clc;
addpath 'C:\matlab_cdf381_patch'
CDFDownloadedWithPatchInfo=spdfcdfinfo("rbsp-a_magnetometer_1sec-gsm_emfisis-L3_20140303_v1.3.2.cdf");
CDFDownloadedWithPatchRead=spdfcdfread("rbsp-a_magnetometer_1sec-gsm_emfisis-L3_20140303_v1.3.2.cdf");
```

The problem is that how to do the same with mathematica? When I tried

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
Import["rbsp-a_magnetometer_1sec-gsm_emfisis-L3_20140303_v1.3.2.cdf", \
"Elements"]
Import["rbsp-a_magnetometer_1sec-gsm_emfisis-L3_20140303_v1.3.2.cdf", \
"Data"]
```

corresponding to the third command, I am getting an output `{"Annotations", "Data", "DataEncoding", "DataFormat", "Datasets", \ "Metadata"}`, but for the last command, I am getting:

> Import::fmterr: Cannot import data as NASACDF format.

> Part::partd:Part specification EvaluatePacket[Null][[All,2]] is longer than depth
> of object.

The first message came as surprise to me because according to this [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/154001/how-to-read-cdf-common-data-format-file), we can import [NASACDF](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/NASACDF.html) files.

So, is there any way that I can import, see and do computation of the data from the type of CDF files that I have mentioned?

Mathematica Version: 11.0.0

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The *Mathematica* documentation on `NASACDF` states "Import supports the NASA CDF 3.1 and earlier versions."  Possibly your file has a later CDF version?  The `AAREADME.txt`  in https://cdaweb.gsfc.nasa.gov/pub/software/cdf/cdf_test_files/  shows the CDF version numbers of each sample file.  The `Import` works for me for `a1_k0_mpa_20050804_v02.cdf` which is version 2.4.7.

Comment: @JimB Thanks for the information. Does it mean that there is no way that we can load and analyze these CDF files in Mathematica?